# Keep previous pages in UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

[image: Mosaic book]

So I want to create an interface like the image above (it is a snapshot form the mosaic app).
When you turn the page this is the kind of behavior happening. 
[image: Mosaic book flipped]

So what is different here is that the cover (the black part) is still visible once you turn the page (the cover is flippable as well, not just a static asset). In a UIViewController when I flip the page it unloads the previous view.
So how do I go about implementing this ?
Any help or nudge in the right direction will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So no replies to this but this question has an upvote this time, I am assuming that someone might stumble into this problem.
So here is how I did it, I used 3 different UIPageViewControllers, for the front cover, the pages and for the back cover.  This will get you to the point where the covers are visible when you are flipping through the pages.
Thanks.

Comment: Use some pageviewcontroller with flip side animation  methods