# how to use 3 uipageviewcontroller together in same view

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

[image: effect like this image have][i have same question like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73oDx.jpg)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4SZ0.jpg): [Keep previous pages in UIPageViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15002005/keep-previous-pages-in-uipageviewcontroller?rq=1) , but the answer here is about using 3 uipageviewcontroller.. how to do that., for inside pages i am using one instance of uipageviewcontroller, as per below code without storyboard.

```
       self.pageViewController = [[UIPageViewController  alloc]initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl     navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationVertical options:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"2",UIPageViewControllerOptionSpineLocationKey,@"0",UIPageViewControllerOptionInterPageSpacingKey, nil]];
self.pageViewController.dataSource = self;


   PageContentViewController *startingViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];
    PageContentViewController *secondViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:1];
    viewControllers = @[startingViewController,secondViewController];
    [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];
    self.pageViewController.doubleSided = YES;




   self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(100,(self.view.frame.size.height-240)/2,self.view.frame.size.width-200, 240);
  [self addChildViewController:self.pageViewController];
  [self.view addSubview:self.pageViewController.view];
  [self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];



 #pragma mark - Page View Controller Data Source and delegate
    - (UIPageViewControllerSpineLocation)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController spineLocationForInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
 {
   if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation))
   {
    //Set the array with only 1 view controller
      PageContentViewController *startingViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];
      viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:startingViewController];
      [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:NULL];


    self.pageViewController.doubleSided = NO;
    return UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMin;
 }
 else
 {

      PageContentViewController *startingViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];
     PageContentViewController *secondViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:1];
     viewControllers = @[startingViewController,secondViewController];
     [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];
     self.pageViewController.doubleSided = YES;
     return UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMid;
  } 

 }

    - (NSUInteger)pageViewControllerSupportedInterfaceOrientations:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0)
{
   return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft ;
}
     -(UIInterfaceOrientation)pageViewControllerPreferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0)
{
   return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
 }
   - (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
  {
   NSUInteger index = ((PageContentViewController*) viewController).pageIndex;

   if ((index == 0) || (index == NSNotFound))
   {
    return nil;
   }

   index--;
   NSLog(@"IndexBackNumber = %d",index);
   return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];

   }
    - (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{

  NSUInteger index = ((PageContentViewController*) viewController).pageIndex;



  if (index == NSNotFound) {
    return nil;
   }

  index++;

 if (index == [self.pageImages count])
{
    return nil;
 }
 NSLog(@"IndexNumber = %d",index);
 return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];

 }
```

this code gives me simple effect like open book, and i can turn its pages, but i want book front cover and back cover, which can flip and stay their when inner pages are flipped. same as shown in above linked question. thank you.

Comment: You could have a look at [coverflow](https://github.com/coverflowjs/coverflow), might be helpful.

Comment: thank u, but its not that wt i want. i want the exact same effect as shown in linked question or like in mosaic photo book app.

Comment: What about the answer to the other question don't you understand / what specifically isn't working?

Comment: i dont understand that how to apply the answer of linked question , how to use that suggested answer, like use 3 uipageviewcontroller, in which sequence or are this 3 uipageviewcontroller in nested loop then how to do that.